# Can I keep the Rueful Axe and get Clavicus Vile's Mask?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to keep the Rueful axe *and* get Clavicus's Mask?  I thought you could kill Barbas after receiving the mask, but he is a statue now.  Did I miss my chance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this particular quest, you can not get both items as reward.

You either kill Barbas (poor mutt) and keep the Rueful Axe.

OR

Hand the axe to Clavicus Vile and receive his true daedric artifact, viz. the Masque of Clavicus Vile.

Important thing to note here is that only the Masque of Clavicus Vile counts towards the Oblivion Walker achievement.

I did try to be clever and decided not to kill Barbas before he turned to stone. This glitched my game worse than ever. Clavicus Vile's statue disappeared.

Please see this page on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend) for further information.

Comment: drat.  I could have sworn I read somewhere it was possible.  oh well, guess that means I don't have to reload a past save to redo the quest at least.

Comment: Its no glitch, its just some kind of odd reaction because most player don't try that. You cannot get both items.

Answer (score 3):

Easy, just press ` to open the console:

If you have taken the axe, type `player.additem 000d2846 1`
If you have taken the mask, type `player.additem 0001c4e6 1`

Comment: Is there no way to do this without the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the axe and the masque, don't listen to that other great answer, because I figured out a way thanks to another comment on another site i saw, but simply changed it a bit. Once given the option too kill Barbus or not quit out of the option screen then save (this is not required, but highly recommended). Once done so go around the statue and open the bared door (if you haven't already) then jump on the chest then on the statue head looking towards the pathway out and make sure you got at least the first shout of whirlwind sprint. talk to him again and say No to killing Barbus, but then quickly press be once you selected it use your whirlwind sprint and get out of the cave! finally once out of the cave quickly quick travel to white run then again use the shout to get to you house. once entering the house put the axe on the weapon rack and afterwards leave again. If you don't got the axe keep on trying until you get it on the weapon rack and be sure before doing all of this you own a house and a weapon rack in that house in Whiterun and have at least one whirlwind sprint shout equipped and I also prefer wearing light armor and your weapon put away. After i left my home I'm not quit sure you have to return to the cave, but i did then i randomly while in the cave got the masque and then returned to my house and still had the axe on the weapon rack.

Comment: You can't remove The Runefull axe it counts as a quest item I treid to put it in a weapon rack ,chest ,body ,ash pile ,even dropping it but the game won't let you so just get the masque its cooler and the axe looks like just a normal steel axe with markings hence RUNE

Comment: @user44124 you can place quest item qeapons on racks.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried this myself so don't blame me if it doesn't work. According to the video, go to the top of the statue after you got the Axe. Talk to him and say you want to give it to him.

While he's in dialogue, use Slow Time and run backwards to the exit. Once outside, go to your house, and place the Axe on the weapon rack, then go back to the cave and the Masque should get added.

I have all updates as of 7/4/2013 (Happy Independence Day), playing on the PS3 and I am able to place quest item (weapons) on weapon racks so whomever says otherwise is full of it.

Comment: Please don't leave link only answers.  If you want to post a YouTube video (which is what it looks like), use the share link.  Also, summarize the content of the link or video.

Comment: @MBraedley I edited that for you!